# how to solve Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error in my Firebase emulator?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I am trying to run the Firestore trigger code below using Firebase emulators, `firebase emulators:start`

as you can see, inside the firestore trigger, I have a code to delete an image stored in Firebase Storage

my code:

```
exports.onDelete = functions
.firestore.document(path)
.onDelete((snapshot, context) => {

    try {

        const deletedUser = new User(snapshot.data());
        const promise1 = db.doc(`devices/${deletedUser.uid}`).delete();

        // deleting the image in Storage
        const defaultBucket = storage.bucket();
        const profilePictureFile = defaultBucket.file(`profilePicture/${deletedUser.uid}`);
        const promise2 = profilePictureFile.delete();

        const promises: Promise<any>[] = [promise1, promise2];
        return Promise.all(promises);

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
    

});
```

because Firebase emulators currently doesn't have emulator for storage, so I expect there will  be an error.

but I have a warning like this

[image]

as you can see at the very bottom, there is a warning that say

> Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error.

is this a serious error? I mean, I think I already provide the try catch block in my code, but why it is still considered as an unhandled error? how to solve this?

sorry, I am a beginner in Node, I am a mobile developer. so I am sorry if my question is a bit silly

Answer (score 6):

Annoying error on every call to firebase functions emulator
[image: Firebase function terminated emulator error]

On MacOS the fix was to remove firebase tools which was originally installed with npm

`npm uninstall -g firebase-tools`

Then install using auto-install script ([Firebase reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install-cli-mac-linux))

`curl -sL https://firebase.tools | bash`

Then onwards whenever update is available

`curl -sL https://firebase.tools | upgrade=true bash`

Comment: I have this exact same issue, but I am not able to install it using `curl -sL firebase.tools | bash` as I get this error: `Warning: Failed to open the file /usr/local/bin/firebase: No such file or directory`. Any idea how to fix it? And, is this an error with the emulator in the first place?

Comment: @allegutta i've fixed the typo in the answer. Use `curl -sL https://firebase.tools | bash`

Comment: Hehe, thanks Fakeer. I was too tired last night to even register the missing `https://` - ended up reinstalling OSX (desperate times call for desperate measures). I can tell you that it also solves the problem ;D

Comment: Believe it or not, using the `https://firebase.tools` instead of `npm` one did the trick

Comment: This worked for me too! Not sure how or why, but glad to be able to test locally again :)

Answer (score 2):

When you don't catch errors generated from Promises, that's considered an unhandled error.  It looks like you're trying to delete an object that doesn't exist, so it's throwing an error that you're not catching in the `Promise.all` call.

To fix your code without changing it substantially, just add a `.catch()` to your `Promise.all()` call.

```
Promise.all(promises)
  .catch(() => console.error("Oh no, an error occurred!"));
```

Simply put, a promise should always have at least one of these functions attached: `.then()`, `.catch()` or `.finally()`

**Bad**

`myFunction.doSomethingReturnPromise();`

**Good**

`myFunction.doSomethingReturnPromise().then();`

Another important point is that `Promise.all()` is all-or-nothing, meaning if one promise fails it exits immediately.  You should instead run each promise individually if there's a chance that the file doesn't exist otherwise you need to create wrapper functions to delete files that always resolve.

Also don't wrap all of your code in a try/catch, instead handle each action individually.  However I'm assuming you don't actually care if it succeeds or not, correct?

Here's how I would write this function:

```
/**
 * Generic delete funcion that will call .delete() on storage objects or database nodes
 * @param doc
 */
const deleteObj = (doc) => {
    return new Promise((resolve: null) => {
        // Delete and resolve no matter what
        doc.delete()
            .finally(() => resolve());
    });
};

exports.onDelete = functions.firestore.document(path).onDelete((snapshot, context) => {
    const deletedUser = new User(snapshot.data());
    const defaultBucket = storage.bucket();

    // Since both types of objects have a similarly named .delete() function, we can use the same function
    // to delete them
    const promises = [
        deleteObj(db.doc(`devices/${deletedUser.uid}`)),
        deleteObj(defaultBucket.file(`profilePicture/${deletedUser.uid}`))
    ];

    Promise.all(promises)
      .finally(() => console.log("All done"));
});
```

Note: In my revised code, since all of the promises given to `Promise.all()` are guaranteed to resolve, I don't need to add a `.catch()` or wrap it in try/catch.

Comment: "When you don't catch errors generated from Promises, that's considered an unhandled error" . this is exactly what I don't understand. in my code above, I already provide the catch error block, so I expect, if the promise2 failed, then the error will be handled by catch block

Comment: Updated my answer with a better explanation.  The only time I use try/catch in my code is with async/await and the revised code shows how I would've written that function.  Promises have built-in error catching magic that you should use instead with `.catch()`

Answer (score 1):

i also faced same issue but with async/await format using try/catch. i also cant figure out until i restarted my emulator and the error magically disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. In my case, I just updated the firebase CLI using the below command.It worked for me.

> npm install -g firebase-tools

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and i tried everything suggested here and nothing worked. I solved the problem by switching my node version 16 (which is the latest supported), I was running the emulator with 19.

I am using nvm for managing my node versions.