# Firebase http function failing locally with ECONNRESET

Tags: node.js, firebase, axios, google-cloud-functions

I have some Firebase Cloud Functions that themselves call some external 3rd party APIs (using axios) and fetch some data.

When these are deployed to production via `firebase deploy` the functions work as expected yay, however when I deploy them locally I get an `ECONNRESET` error in the response and this message in the Firebase emulator

`Your function timed out after ~60s. To configure this timeout...`

It's a strange error message because it appears after 10 seconds or so, not after 60 as it indicates.

After adding in some console logs I can see the connection looks to terminate at the point where I make a call to the external API. I first thought perhaps I wasn't returning my async operations correctly but I don't spot anything that's incorrect. Here's my code:

```
export const createThing = functions
.region(<region>)
.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  try {
    const userId = await getRequestUserId(request);
    const someObject = await generateObject(request.body, userId);
    response.send(someObject);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    response.status(500).send(err);
  }
});
```

```
async function generateObject(inputs: any, userId?: string): Promise<string> {
    const object = await makeAPIRequest(inputs);
    return object
}
```

```
async function makeAPIRequest(prompt: string) {
      const requestData = { <some data>  };
    
      const requestOptions = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {"content-type": "application/json"},
        data: requestData,
        url: <some endpoint>,
      };
    
      return axios(requestOptions)
          .then((res) => {
            const output = res.data[0];
            return output;
          });
    }
```

Obviously I would love to be able to run these locally so that I can test changes before pushing to prod. I've tried hitting the local endpoint via Postman and curl and get the same error. I'm on a Mac and I'm using node v18, not sure if that's relevant.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

OK no idea why this works but managed to solve using [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74843232/2589520).

Essentially removing the Firebase CLI tools

`npm uninstall -g firebase-tools`

And reinstalling using auto-install script (not `npm`!) did the trick.

`curl -sL https://firebase.tools | bash`